# dependent: :destroy throwing error through Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm getting the following error on destroying my model with a CarrierWaveUploader attached to it:

`#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass>`

My model is as follows: Parent > Child > Uploader:

```rb
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
end

class Children < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  has_one :user, :through => :parent

  mount_base64_uploader :file, ChildUploader
end
```

And the line throwing the error in my uploader is the following:

```rb
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.user.id}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

I don't want to use a complicated workaround. It seems that the uploader is not being destroyed properly and still tries to access the store_dir when the parent is already deleted. What's the easiest and cleanest way to fix this?

Comment: Dependent destroy needs to be added in the child model as well against the parent?

Comment: No, destroying a child should not destroy the parent. It seems that the Parent gets destroyed before the Child, which results in the error because of the user not existing anymore.